# How to change date format from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: php, date, format

How to change format of date string using PHP?

From: `06/16/2010`
To: `2010-06-16`

Comment: doesn't explode() works for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date = "06/16/2010";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); // outputs 2010-06-16
```

Using the [strtotime](http://au.php.net/strtotime) function.

Comment: strtotime isn't exactly the most friendly function when you don't have the Y-m-d format as the original date. I've had lots of trouble doing it that way.

Comment: Oh, odd. I don't usually use it too often so I cant comment on it. But seems fine for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `\DateTime` and get rid of strings as soon as possible:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '06/16/2010'); // \DateTime object
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2010-06-16
```

See more:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

`php -r 'echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("06/16/2010"));'`