# Change data format from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, string, date, trim

I have data string with data in format like this -> `03/15/2014 (mm/dd/yyyy)` and I need to replace that with date in format `2014-03-15 (yyyy-mm-dd)`.

I know how to change '/' to '-', but I don't know how to turn 2014 from end to start.

Comment: Did you look in the PHP manual at the date/time functions and/or DateTime class?

Comment: People don't know hot so use google sometimes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change date format from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074525/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: By the way it's `date` not `data`, could not correct this (Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$dates = explode("/","03/15/2014");
$newdate = $dates[2]."-".$dates[0]."-".$dates[1];
```

This works in all version of php

**Note:** the input date should be of format `mm/dd/yyyy`

If your php is less than 5 you can use this. If `php > 5` then it advised to use Datetime class as advised by `GordonM` in order to find the date is valid or not .

[**Demo**](http://3v4l.org/7SiXa)

Comment: Not the downvoter , You should actually use the `DateTime` class

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran correct. But `DateTime` class starts from `php5` only

Comment: Not the downvoter. Though this answer IS INVALID the OP wants yyyy-mm-dd NOT yyyy-dd-mm as your proposal says.

Comment: @Wimpie ahhh. didnt notice that. thanks for spotting. i will edit it

Comment: This is not a particularly good answer as it will only ever work the the specified input format, any other format will break it.

Comment: @Novocaine88 i dont accept your point, the question is to change `mm/dd/yyy` to `yyy/mm/dd`. so why do you want to think of other things ?

Comment: @krishna While it does answer the question correctly, this method provides no scope to work with other date formats. Other answers provided do and with less code. If code can be created to be more compatible with future development with ease, it should be.

Comment: i can accept only one point of yours `Other answers provided do and with less code`. others i cannot accept. what if required  date format is `d-m-Y`. then all answers fails. come on guys. if you start think of input format start think of output format also. Probably i can add a note saying how the input format should be.

Comment: @Novocaine88 `date()` also fails if input format is `Y-M-d`. check here http://3v4l.org/ZIuXq

Comment: -1, this is merely doing string manipulation and no sanity checking.  If I input 31st of Feb as a date, as long as the string format is right it will happily return 31st of Feb as output.  You should really use PHP's date/time functionality which will fail on invalid dates so you can detect and handle them better.

Comment: @GordonM. you are right.Atlast i got a good reason `why should we use php functions` for dates.

Comment: @GordonM php date/time function will not fail.it will give you wrong date. If a person checking that o/p date is wrong , why can't he check for wrong i/p dates ? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @GordonM It could be considered as additional score for other answers yet it does not invalidate this particular one.

Comment: @krishna `$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '02/31/2014'); var_dump ($dt -> getLastErrors ());`

Comment: @GordonM. right. but with `DateTime` class only you have this function and not with date() function. right ?

Comment: @krishna That's why I recommended using the class :)

Comment: @GordonM, thanks for informing about cool feature of `DateTime` class.now i have added a note which informs about this problem

Answer (score 6):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('03/15/2014'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [**`DateTime::format`**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
 $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', ' 03/15/2014');
 echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: +1, but you might want to include a `$dt -> getLastErrors ()` to make sure the date wasn't nonsense.  For example 31st of Feb 2014 will be treated as 3rd of March (28th + 3 days) which might be what you want but it never hurts to check

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = '03/15/2014';
$time1 = strtotime($date1);
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just explode the string and replace accordingly:

```
$str = explode('/', $date);
$result = $str[2].'-'.$str[0].'-'.$str[1];
```

Comment: -1, this is merely doing string manipulation and no sanity checking. If I input 31st of Feb as a date, as long as the string format is right it will happily return 31st of Feb as output. You should really use PHP's date/time functionality which will fail on invalid dates so you can detect and handle them better.

Comment: @GordonM You sure you read the question? It was not about date validation.

Comment: @Cthulhu Yes I did but you should always be making sure your data is valid anyway, otherwise you might find yourself trying to send a birthday card on the 31st of February.