# change date format using php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want change a date format by php,
I have a date in format like this `d/m/Y` and I want to change to `Y-m-d`

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074525/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd) 
but for my case, I still get an empty value.

`EX:$_REQUEST["date_moc"]='21/07/2014';`
I tried to do `echo strtotime($_REQUEST["date_moc"]);` but nothing to shows up on my screen.

and when I `echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_REQUEST["date_moc"]));` I get `1970-01-01`

Any help please,I am really wonder with my code that return empty value like, if possible please tell me with my problem. I am looking forward to see your reply soon!

Thanks!

Comment: str_replace('/','-',$_REQUEST["date_moc"])

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way

```
$_REQUEST["date_moc"]='21/07/2014';
$explode = explode('/', $_REQUEST["date_moc"]);
list($day,$month,$year) = $explode;
$new_date = "$year-$month-$day";
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: And also the most efficient way. If the OP wants to also use other date formats, he could use DateTime.

Comment: the simplest way and most generic way is given by @TiMESPLiNTER

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy just use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '21/07/2014');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

See the [live demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/170291)

---

**For enhancement**

You can then also check against invalid input if you extend the snippet above a bit:

```
if(($date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '21//2014')) !== false)
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
else
    echo 'Invalid format';
```

But this is only a pattern check which is similar to a regex like

> /(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})/

This still allows the user to enter something like:

> 50/13/2014

To check wether the provided date is valid or invalid check the content of [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.getlasterrors.php). It will tell you in detail what went wrong. For the example above you'll get something like this:

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [10]=>
    string(27) "The parsed date was invalid"
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

So according to this information we can extend the snippet again a bit. Which leads us to a result similar like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '50/13/2014')

if($date !== false) {
    $dateLastErrors = $date->getLastErrors();

    if($dateLastErrors['error_count'] > 0 || $dateLastErrors['warning_count'] > 0)
        echo 'Invalid date';
    else
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
} else
    echo 'Invalid date format';
}
```

Which will finally check the date against format an validation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :- **[Working Demo](http://codepad.org/buSwZQ5N)**

```
$date = explode('/',str_replace('-','/',$_REQUEST["date_moc"]));

$updated_date = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];

echo $updated_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_REQUEST["date_moc"]='21/07/2014';
$original_date = explode('/', $_REQUEST["date_moc"]);
$year = $original_date[2]; // 2014
$month = $original_date[1]; // 07
$day =  $original_date[0]; // 21
$date = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$day;
echo $date;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/170294)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = $_REQUEST["date_moc"];// OR $date ='21/07/2014'; avoid $_REQUEST["date_moc"]='21/07/2014';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way

```
$date ='21/07/2014';

$date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);

echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

**[Working Demo](https://eval.in/170290)**